# Where do an Eclipse's plugins log files go to?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin which is failing. I developed/enhanced it based off of another plugin. When I deploy this plugin as an update site and install it into another instance of eclipse, it works initially (the view shows up). But as I try to interact and use the view, it's functionality is broke (it doesn't do anything when I click a given button). I don't see any error on the screen and nothing in the Eclipse Error Log view shows up.

I want to know where/if it has any error log files by default? If it had any custom loggers where would these sent to? I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).

If I want to find out the cause of this exception must I implement my own custom log files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, The error log file will be in your "eclipse workspace"\.metadata\.log
But that's just the file that shows up in the Eclipse Error Log view.

If the plugin you are using had some sort of extra logging (I doubt it) the logical place for it would be "eclipse workspace"\.metadata\.plugins\{plugin.name}" although that depends on the application..

If your application works when you debug it, but doesn't work when you deploy it, it's probably some sort of deployment issue..  Eclipse can be very very picky about picking up new versions of jars.  Make sure you update your manifest version or delete your work space before doing an install.  Another thing that can happen is you are missing plugins or plugin fragements that are needed or the minimum version specified isn't correct.

You don't *have to* implement logging.  You can use eclipse to attach a debugger to your deployed application and then debug the application as you would normally.  Although, if you plan on selling your application, logging is always a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse installed directory and inside .metadata folder there will be a log file without name. That will be the plugin log